# Does the fact that $f(n)$ is not $o(g(n))$ and $f(n)$ is not $\omega(g(n))$ imply that $f(n)$ is $\Theta(g(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

Is this statement true?
$$f(n) \notin o(g(n))~~~\wedge~~~f(n) \notin \omega(g(n))~~\implies f(n)\in\Theta(g(n))$$

I'm thinking that because $f(n)$ is never greater than or less than $cg(n)$, then it must be growing at the same rate? However I don't know how to derive this solution from first principles.

Comment: what's  your definition of those 3 simbols? (If it's what I have in mind, then it's false, since $f(n)=sin (n)$ and $g(n)=1$ are not comparable)

Comment: what is this $\omega$ thing?

Answer (score 1):

In general, not every two functions are comparable asymptotically.
Consider $f(x) = e^{x\cos(x)}$ and $g(x) = x$.